# Swift:fetchedResultsController.getter: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

I was doing a chat app, but when running it, it showed that in fetchedResultsController.getter(closure #1),there is a fatal error:unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. I double checked it, but found nothing wrong. Could you help me fix it?

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController:NSFetchedResultsController = {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Friend")
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"date", ascending: true)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "friend.name = %@", self.friend!.name!)

    let delegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as!
    AppDelegate
    let context = delegate.managedObjectContext

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    frc.delegate = self
    return frc
}()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the only place in where you are unwrapping optional values is in this line I'm guessing that self.friend is nil at this point.

```
  fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "friend.name = %@", self.friend!.name!)
```

You should figure out why

Comment: I think the root reason lies in my misunderstanding of NSPredicate:when to return array,when to return string.I should dig more into Core Data tutorial.

Comment: where and when self.friend is set is the key question I think, you could share that bit of code or explain how is this done